# Error Package file was not signed corrctly

Tags: java, android, google-play

I am trying to learn how to put apps out in the market and I made a quick JS-Light (Flashlight) app with Esclipe-IDE. I did and export of a signed package and uploaded to the market.  it downloads and then I get the following error

Error Package file was not signed corrctly

Comment: I hope you created a release keystore, because it won't work if you try to use the debug.keystore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've been testing your application on your phone, the application package on your phone has been signed with a different debug key, whereas the package you uploaded to the Market is signed with your own key.

In order for an application to be replaced with a new version of it, the keys have to match. An ordinary user will have no trouble downloading your app and installing it.